# Please use a personal access token instead. (But using one)

Tags: git, github, personal-access-token

```
Username for 'https://github.com': username
Password for 'https://username@github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/username/repo.git/'
```

I'm still receiving this error despite using personal access token, and it has been working fine for about 6 months, it has no expiration date.

But now I'm trying to pull some changes on my vps and this error appears.

I've created a new access token but still getting the same error.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solve the problem by setting origin url before push or pull something, just like this:

```
~$ git remote set-url origin https://<githubtoken>@github.com/<username>/<repositoryname>.git

~$ git pull origin <branch>
```

As it says here [“Support for password authentication removed” for GitHub. How to Generate Personal Access Token?](https://magecomp.com/blog/generate-personal-access-token-github/)

Comment: now it says `Password for 'https://<my_github_token>@github.com':`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on my console or on my Git Bash when I tried to use

> git push -u origin main

Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt. remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/JaseemKhan211/myNatours.git'

It's weird because today I have a lot of time to fix this error. To push the code to my GitHub repository, I open Git Bash and run the first command.

> git init

then, all commands are run one by one.

> git status
>
> git add.
>
> git status
>
> git commit -m "first commit"
>
> git status
>
> git remote add origin  https://github.com/JaseemKhan211/myNatours.git
>
> git push -u origin main

The last executed command resulted in a window open, prompting for a username and password to be filled. However, upon attempting to fill out this information, an error was displayed in the console.

I fixed the problem just simply by upgrading Git to the latest version!

Now instead of adding your username/email and password, you will login with your browser. The image below is the new interface you must update your Git to see the new changes!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM45C.png)

If you are using Windows, you can simply use this command below to update your Git:

> git update-git-for-windows

Then update Git and then proceed to run the last command once more.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42v4C.png)

After successful login, we got this message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJCMz.png)